# Datatable Slot Issue with builded Admin scripts

Tags: shopware6

Unfortunately I noticed that when I use a sw-data-grid and specify an action slot there with the parameter item, that it works wonderfully when I call the whole thing via watch-administration.sh.

```
<sw-data-grid :data-source="dataSource" :columns="columns" :showSelection="false">
            <template #actions="{ item }">
                <sw-context-menu-item
                        class="sw-entity-listing__context-menu-edit-delete"
                        variant="danger"
                        @click="openDeleteModal(item.id)"
                >
                    {{ $tc('global.default.delete') }}
                </sw-context-menu-item>
            </template>
</sw-data-grid>
```

But if I call build-administration.sh and then the page, I get the following error:

```
An error was captured in current module: ReferenceError: item is not defined
    at fn (eval at da (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1972611), <anonymous>:3:5249)
    at i (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1895744)
    at s._t (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1896582)
    at s.eval (eval at da (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1972611), <anonymous>:3:1885)
    at e._render (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1915484)
    at s.i (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1948615)
    at wn.get (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1906868)
    at wn.run (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1907752)
    at mn (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1905860)
    at Array.<anonymous> (vendors-node.js?16866007802408938:2:1892459)
```

Have I possibly overlooked something?

Kind regards

Tried to open the module outside of watch-administration.sh

Answer (score 0):

Issue found - The issue was, that the modal to open, contained an item element - which was not found.

But cant even understand, why its worked in watch-administration.sh mode - Maybe someone can explain?

Comment: I think watch-administration uses the dev build?

Comment: You mean there‘s something behind?

Comment: yes, there might be differences due to the dev build - but this actually should be very rare